# How to load either one or another .so?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

My app makes use of a shared library, say, `mylib.so`

This `mylib.iso` would like to use API from either `lib1.so` or `lib2.so` depending on some condition.

Both `lib1.so` and `lib2.so` provide the exact same set of API.

I can only calculate the condition once `mylib.iso` has been loaded. It does not depend on APIs from `lib1.so` or `lib2.so` but I can not do from java:

```
static {
   if(nativeHasCondition()) System.loadLibrary("lib1");
   else System.loadLibrary("lib2");
}
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

}

because `nativeHasCondition()` is in `mylib.so`.

So, I think I shall somehow load either `lib1.so` or `lib2.iso` from my native code depending on some calculation in my native code.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If nativeHasCondition() is the method of mylib.so, then you have to load mylib.so first. 
Then you can follow the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should make that code into a separate library and load it first. If you need to test cpu caps, probably you should just do it from java and then load appropriate libs (as long as you manage to load your mylib.so which should reference lib1.so or lib2.so in its import section).